# Set position in a file in fortran?

Tags: fortran90

How do I set the position in a file in Fortran. As far as I understand, `INQUIRE(unit, pos=currentpos)` returns the current position in the file. How do I set the position to currentpos?

I know there's FSEEK, but it appears to be a portability layer on POSIX in ifort. I would prefer a standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no other way then fseek or lseek to set the position in a file.